# Need to count number of instances of a specific word

Tags: c++

I have a homework problem that wants a program that will count the number of instances of a specific word in the users input. It only needs to count the words between whitespace. I'm thinking we need to use a vector, and add on to it every time an instance of "word" appears. Then at the end, use v.size() to tell the size of the vector. This is what I have so far, but it won't compile, I'm pretty sure its not right:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string word;
  vector<string> v;
  while (cin >> word)
  {
    if (v == "word")
    {
      v.push_back (word);
    }
  }
  cout << v.size();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Independent of any compiler errors: you don't really need to push the into a `std::vector<std::string>` to count how often it happens! Your error is, BTW, that you probably meant to compare `word` against `"word"` rather than comparing `v` against `"word"`.

Comment: why use a vector if you are only going to get the size of it? Have a counter and increment it when the word appears. Also "It won't compile" doesn't help us. What errors does it give.

Answer (score 3):

1. `if(v == "word")` - you are trying to compare your vector `v` with a "word" string. The input is stored in a `word` variable. If your word to count is "word", then it should be `if(word == "word")`.
2. You don't need to `push_back` your words - you know perfectly well they are all the same, right? Instead make a counter variable and increment it each time the desired word is encountered.

These ideas should get you started.

Comment: I forgot to mention that it actually needs to count 4 different instances of word -- Word, word, Words, words. I wasnt sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: @user2789474 then you will have to check against all 4. `if( word == "word" || word == "Word" || ... )`

Answer (score 1):

The v == "word" doesn't make sense to me. v is a vector, correct? If so, v == "word" is comparing a vector of Strings to a string, which doesn't work.

I would personally suggest using a map or dictionary.
Here's documentation on c++ maps. Amazing data structures 0.0

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

The way I did a similar exercise when in University was like so:

```
//Pseudocode activate
Map<string, int> my_map = new Map();
String word;
while(there is input){
    my_map.at(word)++;
}

for all entries in my_map{
    print my_map keys: my_map values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to count the number of "word", you can use something like:

```
int count = -1;
do
{
cout << "Word: ";
cin >> word;
count++;
system("cls");
}while(condition)
printf("Result:%d", cout);
```

and a count to get the number of condition == true